# How can i know whether "bias" exists in a layer?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I'm trying to read weight and bias in a caffe network with pycaffe.
Here is my code

```
weight = net.params[layer_name][0].data
bias = net.params[layer_name][1].data
```

But, some layers in my network has no bias, so that there will be an error which is `Index out of range`.

So my question is can I use

```
if(net.params[layer_name][1] exists):
    bias = net.params[layer_name][1].data
```

to control the assignments to `bias`?
And how to write the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply iterate over `net.params[layer_name]`:

```
layer_params = [blob.data for blob in net.params[layer_name]]
```

This way, you get all `layer_params` (which might be more than 2 for some layers, e.g., [`"BatchNorm"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/batchnorm.html))

If you only want to check for the second parameters blob, you can use `len`:

```
if len(net.params[layer_name]) >= 2:
    bias = net.params[layer_name][1].data
```

---

PS,
It might be the case that `net.params[layer_name]` is not exactly a python `list`, but rather some python boost wrapper object, thus you might need to explicitly cast it to list (`list(net.params[layer_name])`) in some of the methods I suggested in this answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!
It works!
But, actually, that is `len(net.params[layer_name]) >= 2`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do it for convolution layers, you can find whether the layer has bias through reading the prototxt without the need for the caffemodel, i.e.

```
from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2
import google.protobuf.text_format
net = caffe_pb2.NetParameter()
f = open('model.prototxt', 'r')
net = google.protobuf.text_format.Merge(str(f.read()), net)
f.close()
for i in range(0, len(net.layer)):
    if net.layer[i].type == 'Convolution':
        if net.layer[i].convolution_param.bias_term == True:
            print 'layer has bias'
```