# How can I know if there is no Bias exists in a layer using caffe framwork with c++ program

Tags: c++, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, bias-neuron

I'm trying to read weight and bias in a caffe framework with c++. Here is my code

```
shared_ptr<Blob<float> >& weight = current_layer->blobs()[0];//for weights
shared_ptr<Blob<float> >& bias = current_layer->blobs()[1];//for bias
```

But if for some model the bias is not present or defined it throughs a segmentation fault error.

**So which function returns a boolean value which indicates the presens of bias and how to call the function in c++?**

Comment: Why `shared_ptr<Blob<float> >& weight` and not `shared_ptr<Blob<float> > weight`? If you only take a reference to a shared pointer the object may be destroyed because taking reference does not increase the internal reference count. Dereferencing the shared pointer reference may produce the undefined behavior.

Comment: I got it and try the above suggested method Rex. can you please answer the above mentioned question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `blobs` returned from `current_layer->blobs()` are stored in a [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector), you can use its `size` property:

```
if (current_layer->blobs().size() > 1) {
    shared_ptr<Blob<float> >& bias = current_layer->blobs()[1];//for bias
}
```

See [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46663514/1714410) for python interface for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
const std::vector<string> lnames = net_->layer_names();

for (int layer_index = 0; layer_index < net_->layer_names().size(); ++layer_index)
{
     const shared_ptr<Layer<float> > CAlayer = net_->layer_by_name(lnames[layer_index]);
     std::cout << lnames[layer_index] << std::endl;

     if(CAlayer->blobs().size() > 1)
     {
             std::cout << "weight-shape" << CAlayer->blobs()[0]->shape_string() << std::endl;
             std::cout << "weight-count" << CAlayer->blobs()[0]->count() << std::endl;
             std::cout << "bias-shape" << CAlayer->blobs()[1]->shape_string() << std::endl;
             std::cout << "bias-count" << CAlayer->blobs()[1]->count() << std::endl;
     }
}
```

Eventally the data (weights & bias params) can be fetched from

```
 CAlayer->blobs()[0]->cpu_data()[...]
```